# Why does SSH on Raspberry disconnects when USB 3.0 is connected?

Tags: usb, ssh, pi-4, ubuntu

```
Hardware: Raspberry PI 4B.
Connected to the Chinese adapter 5V - 3A.
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 (GNU / Linux 5.3.0-1022-raspi2 aarch64).
```

The situation is this: when I connected to the raspberry over SSH, I connect a 1TB hard drive into the USB 3.0 port and get a drop of the SSH session.
Restart RPI, ssh does not up. There was a theory that the whole thing is in power, so I tried to connect RPI using an adapter from a MacBook (the one that produces up to 85W), I repeat all the steps - nothing changed.

I tried to take a USB flash drive with USB 2.0, connect it in both ports 3.0 and 2.0, there were no problems. I took a USB flash drive with USB 3.0, everything works in ports 2.0 but when I connect it to the 3.0 port - the session crashes.

Interesting, when Ethernet is connected to the RPI, the ssh session does not drop when USB 3.0 is connected (both the session from the local network via the IP of the Wi-Fi module and the session via the external white IP), but as soon as I disconnect Ethernet, all sessions are disconnected.
And when Ethernet connected back, sessions up again (immediately and without restarts).
Similarly, a session up almost immediately when a disk is disconnected.

Logs from syslog:

```
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu systemd-networkd[1171]: eth0: Lost carrier
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu kernel: [80410.727887] bcmgenet fd580000.genet eth0: Link is Down
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu systemd-networkd[1171]: eth0: DHCP lease lost
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu dbus-daemon[1298]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=101 pid=1171 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd " label="unconfined")
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1292]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.31.212 on eth0.
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1292]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.31.212.
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1292]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu dbus-daemon[1298]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 13 17:49:45 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr 13 17:50:15 ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
Apr 13 17:50:26 ubuntu kernel: [80451.528566] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
Apr 13 17:50:26 ubuntu kernel: [80451.530583] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Apr 13 17:50:26 ubuntu kernel: [80451.530789] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Apr 13 17:50:26 ubuntu multipathd[1176]: sda: path already removed
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.744546] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.766803] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=b207, bcdDevice= 3.15
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.766811] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.766815] usb 2-2: Product: External USB 3.0
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.766819] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.766823] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 20180524007993F
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.769589] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.769854] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.619877] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 5438 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.622143] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.623845] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525164 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.624307] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.624320] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.631220] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.649131]  sda: sda1
Apr 13 17:50:32 ubuntu kernel: [80457.651948] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu kernel: [80479.336883] bcmgenet fd580000.genet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu systemd-networkd[1171]: eth0: Gained carrier
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu NetworkManager[1299]: <info>  [1586800253.9297] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu dbus-daemon[1298]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.1' (uid=101 pid=1171 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd " label="unconfined")
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu systemd-networkd[1171]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.31.212/24 via 192.168.31.1
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1292]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.31.212.
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1292]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu avahi-daemon[1292]: Registering new address record for 192.168.31.212 on eth0.IPv4.
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu systemd-networkd[1171]: eth0: Configured
Apr 13 17:50:53 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Apr 13 17:50:54 ubuntu dbus-daemon[1298]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Apr 13 17:50:54 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Apr 13 17:50:54 ubuntu systemd-hostnamed[2357]: Changed host name to 'MiWiFi-R1CM-srv'
```

In general, to connect an external drive (be it a flash drive or hard drive) with USB 3.0 to RPI, I did not find any options other than connecting it to the 2.0 port.
Tell me why this is happening, and can I fix it?

P.S. Sorry for my poor English, but I don’t even know where I can find the answer to this question.

Comment: check the USB 3 connector for damage

Comment: It's not possible for a USB-C supply to deliver more than 15W at 5V. The fact that it's for a Mac is in no way a guarantee it's good for the Pi. Also, clarify how you connect the Pi to the network. I see "eth0: Lost carrier" even before the disk is connected, so I assume it's not built-in Ethernet. What is it then?

Comment: @jsotola, both USB 3.0 seem to be working, and they work the same.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, "eth0 lost carrier" this is a message that I manually unplugged the cable. All actions essentially begin with a message: `Apr 13 17:50:28 ubuntu kernel: [80453.744546] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd` But in this log there is absolutely nothing about wlan, as if nothing had happened to it. And yes, eth and wlan are both modules on the board.

Comment: @Danij I know what this message means. I'm asking how you connect the Pi to the network.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, It is connected via wifi (2.4GHz router), and I also tried to connect via the built-in Ethernet (by the way, the SSH session does not disappear).